# How to authenticate and authorize in corporation environment?

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, windows-server

I'm new in developing Web APIs, read a lot about it but I have several questions. First of all, what I want to do:

1. I have to develop for a corporation with many Windows users, so Windows authentication is recommended.
2. A REST API which handles http requests from users.
3. A Web application which uses the API, renders HTML and interacts with users...

My questions would be mostly about Windows authentication and authorization.

1. If I thought right, the API and Web app should be 2 separate projects. In this case how the authentication works? I just simply set the Windows authentication in both projects and everything is fine?
2. What is the correct way to restrict some features, like POST methods? For example if I want to grant permission to update the database only for 1 man, how can I do that? Keep the user roles in an SQL datatable? Or user claims made up for that?
3. Is it possible to grant permissions to users without accessing the Active Directory on the server? How?
4. How can I create application-specific user rights?
5. How can I test authorization on my local computer?

I do not have any experience, please share with me the good practices and indicate if a question is not clear.

Comment: Does the organization has azure active directory? Creating web APIs on top of AAD apps is probably the simplest for orgs.

Comment: No, doesnt have, only Windows Server.